# Pygame screen freezes in the middle of a function that renders text one character at a time

Tags: python, text, pygame, render, freeze

I am new to Stack Overflow and to both pygame and python in general, so please forgive me if I made a very simple mistake. I am trying to display text one character at a time in a pygame screen. My function works fine, rendering what I want it to, except that it randomly freezes, displaying "Not Responding" in the caption area, at inconsistent times (e.g. sometimes it will freeze after rendering 10 letters, sometimes after 28, etc). This happens even after I restart my computer. My question is: Is this just happening to me, or is it something wrong with my code, and if it is something wrong with my code, please help me fix it. Here is my code, and thank you in advance:

```
import pygame, time
from pygame.locals import *
width = 800
height = 800

pygame.init()
scrn = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height)) 

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 22) 

def render_text(string, bg = None, text_color = (0, 0, 0), surf = scrn, width = width, height = height):
    text = '' 
    for i in range(len(string)): 
        if bg == None:
            surf.fill((255, 255, 255))
        else:
            surf.blit(bg, (0, 0))
        text += string[i] 
        text_surface = font.render(text, True, text_color) 
        text_rect = text_surface.get_rect() 
        text_rect.center = (width/2, height/2)
        surf.blit(text_surface, text_rect) 
        pygame.display.update() 
        time.sleep(0.05) 

def intro():

    while True: #just used as an example, it will freeze up usually sometime during the first or second iteration
        render_text("It was a dark and stormy night.")
        time.sleep(2)

intro()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pygame programs that don't use the events queue should call [pygame.event.pump](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) every iteration instead.  This will prevent the freezing from occurring.  Changing the `intro` function to look like this should work:

```
def intro():
    while True:
        pygame.event.pump()
        render_text("It was a dark and stormy night.")
        time.sleep(2)
```